# Facebook App Install not recorded in Facebook Insights [iOS App]

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-insights

I am trying to track down the installs in my iOS app in the Facebook Insights panel and i am not really able to do it. The only reading that i get is the number of App Launches. App install data is not getting recorded.

When i went through the insights panel i came across a banner as follows

"This data can be incomplete as we do not seem to be receiving app launch events corresponding to all your app installs"

Can you please help me with a solutions to track the no of App installs in Facebook Insights panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the FB iOS SDK then this logging is done by the use of FBSDKAppEvents class as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/ios#implementation).
One reason I can think of why you cannot see the data is that you do not have enough data. Wait for more data to log and see if it works.

If you are working with Mobile ads then make sure you follow the instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads). There is an [App Ads Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper) as well that you might find handy.